# How to include additional scripts in basil.js

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

New to Basil.js, but love it dearly.

I am wondering if it is possible to link other javascript sheets in my .jsx script and what the correct procedure is. When I try:

**#include "basiljs/users/anotherscript.jsx";**

InDesign throws err:

**Error Number: 48
Offending Text: #include "basiljs/users/anotherscript.jsx";**

Answer (score 1):

yes you can normal includes :) the example below shows for instance how to include [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to your basil sketch. please note the very first line with "#includepath", this line basically includes the whole document folder for mac and pc ... then you can specify from there on a relative path to the file for including.

```
#includepath "~/Documents/;%USERPROFILE%Documents";
#include "basiljs/bundle/basil.js";
#include "basiljs/libraries/underscore.js";

function draw() {
  var result = _.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
  b.println( result );
}

b.go();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use include that way in extendscript.

However this WILL work:

```
//include another script
$.evalFile(new File("basiljs/users/anotherscript.jsx"));
```

If it doesn't work, try a full path to your script.

```
$.evalFile(new File("/c/somefolder/basiljs/users/anotherscript.jsx"));
```